# How to save image to a folder and retrieve when needed

Tags: c#-4.0

```
private void btn_Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "image files |*.jpg;";
    DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
}
```

I'm using this code to get a picture in the picture box, but I want to save the image in a folder so I could show it to the user again later.

Comment: may help this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database

Comment: thanx i will check thix..

Comment: but bro.. i want to save the picture in a folder and just link to database..

Comment: you need to save image name in data base and at the time of retrival image u just get the image name from database and append tha folder path coded .

Comment: so it helps you i have implemented it.

Comment: no i have not implemented it yet.. becoz i didnot find a suitable way of doing this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(fbd.SelectedPath + txtFileName + ".jpg");
        }
    }
```

where txtFileName ix the textBox in which u will write the name of the image u want to save.